# How to import maven dependencies from nexus and from local .m2 repo?

Tags: java, maven, import, nexus

I want to understand that how exactly does the IntelliJ's "Reimport all maven projects" work. Does it fetch the dependencies from remote nexus repo or from the local .m2. Also, from where does the Auto-import fetch it? 
Do they first search in local .m2 and if not found then go to remote or vice versa?

Comment: The standard Maven way is: Look in the local repository. If not found, fetch from remote. Only SNAPSHOTs behave differently because they are updated on a regular basis. I guess that IntelliJ does the same.

Comment: The Maven behavior can be specified in the settings.xml folder.  IntelliJ will do what it is told to do.  JF Meier is correct: first local .m2, then Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

As per as i know "Reimport all maven projects" basically instruct IntelliJ to refresh its own cache from local .m2 folder. It doesn't fetch's those from remote repo.

"Auto-import" basically looks into .m2 and then check the remote if those dependencies are not available when there is change in pom.xml.